# 例えばですが、cakephpの中にrubyを使いたいなど

Tags: php

使用しているフレームワーク内で違う言語を使用したりはできるものですか？
できるとしたら、それはどんな場合ですか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

できること

- 端末から `ruby hoge.rb` として実行するように、PHP から Rubyプログラムを実行する
- ブラウザから `http://localhost/some-rails-app/hoge` とするように、サーバー上で動いている Ruby アプリケーションに PHP から GET/POST リクエストを投げる

できないこと

- PHP のソースコード中に Ruby のソースコードを書く
- `require 'hoge.rb'` といった感じに Ruby のプログラムを読み込む
- Ruby で CakePHP のコントローラやモデルを書く
- Ruby から CakePHP の機能を呼び出す

大雑把に言えば、こんな感じです。

基本的には異なる言語の間をシームレスにつなぐのは難しいため、独立したプログラムとして作っておき、標準入出力やファイル、もしくは WebAPI などの形でデータを受け渡すことになります。